# "Monotouch is not installed" error

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin.ios, installation, monodevelop

I am trying to build a sample app using Monotouch. I have this configuration/setup with me - Xcode 3.2.6, Mac OS X 10.6 and iOS 4.3. I have also installed latest Mono framework (2.10.8) and latest version of Mono Develop.

When I try to create my first app, (by following the article [MonoTouch Hello World](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/getting_started/hello_iphone) ), then I get the error "The MonoTouch SDK could not be detected. Either it has never been installed or an update of XCode has removed the SDK...."

I reinstalled and installed MonoFramework, MonoDevelop and Monotouch (In this order itself) muliple times, but that does not resolve my problem.

Can someone please guide me for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is missing the MonoTouch version that you're using. It can be important since the latest versions of MonoDevelop will require a recent version of MonoTouch.

Also the latest version of MonoDevelop are meant to be compatible with Xcode 4.x and that will be important if you want to use Interface Builder to create your user interfaces (that part changed a lot from Xcode 3.2.x).

Finally if you did not install MonoTouch in it's default directory (i.e. `/Developer/MonoTouch`) then you will need to configure MonoDevelop to tell it where MonoTouch is installed. Go to:

- the **MonoDevelop** menu;
- select **Preferences...** item;
- select **SDK Locations** in the tree view (under others); and
- set the directory for **MonoTouch SDK**

> Can someone please guide me for the same.

This MonoTouch [tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/getting_started/installation) will guide you if you use *all recent* versions of Xcode, MonoDevelop and MonoTouch.

Comment: Thanks.. Changing default directory has helped.. (But to be frank, I was also playing with couple of other things, so unsure which one fixed).. Also later when I went further with hello world, then at one point it stopped where it said, It needs XCode 4.2.. Now I have to go a long route since my OS is Snow Leopard and there is no XCode 4.2 for Snow Leopard, I have to upgrade to Lion.. Let's see how it goes further.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You **can** download and install Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard. However it's a **separate** download from the version for Lion which is available on the Mac Application Store. You'll need to download it from the Apple Developer's web site.